# how to show different pop up on click of button in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am trying to show some modal pop up on a button click. I am able to display pop up but I am trying to display different pop up on the button click. In my code I take different HTML of pop up but when I click any button it show same pop up.Could you please tell me how to show different pop up screen on different button click

Here is my different pop up screen

```
   <script id="templates/modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">New Contact</h1>
          <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
              <input ng-model="newUser.firstName" type="text">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
              <input ng-model="newUser.lastName" type="text">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Email</span>
              <input ng-model="newUser.email" type="text">
            </label>
            <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="modal.hide()">Create</button>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
        <script id="templates/copymodal.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">copy Contact</h1>
          <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">copy first Name</span>
              <input ng-model="newUser.firstName" type="text">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
              <input ng-model="newUser.lastName" type="text">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Email</span>
              <input ng-model="newUser.email" type="text">
            </label>
            <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="modal.hide()">Create</button>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
```

**js file**
// Code goes here

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {

$scope.firstpopup=function(){
  $scope.modal.show()
}


$scope.secondpopup=function(){
  $scope.modal.show()
}
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });


  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/copymodal.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

});
```

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/KXzUO5OL6Imy9yKP0Ktq?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the modals differently on your scope. Something like this should work.

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {

$scope.firstpopup=function(){
  $scope.modalFirst.show()
}


$scope.secondpopup=function(){
  $scope.modalSecond.show()
}
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modalFirst = modal;
  });


  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/copymodal.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modalSecond = modal;
  });

});
```

You will also have to change the index.html to make sure that while closing the correct modal is being closed.

**Update:** http://plnkr.co/edit/10NPJIdDHrq6c9HhEchh?p=info